# Mysql Show all admin users but not the admin who is logged in

Tags: php, mysql

om my web app i have an admin page where in the admin can add new admin users and view all the list of admin users, my question how can do the query to select all the admin users but not showing the admin itself that is logged in.

So far this is my query :

```
<div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>admin_id</th><th>Username</th><th>Date Registered</th><th>Added By</th><th>Status</th><th></th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT `admin_id`,`username`,`reg_date`,`added_by`,`status` FROM `admin`";

                if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
                    if($stmt->execute()) {
                        $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $reg_date, $added_by, $status);
                        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            ?>              <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td><td><?php echo $username; ?></td><td><?php echo date('M j, Y', strtotime($reg_date)); ?></td><td><?php echo $added_by; ?></td><td><?php echo $status; ?></td><td><a href="">Deactivate</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Should i use Where Clause on my query? but how? any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT `admin_id`,`username`,`reg_date`,`added_by`,`status`
    FROM `admin`
    WHERE `username` != ?";

if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $variable_containing_the_logged_in_username); // Change this variable to match wherever you have the info
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $reg_date, $added_by, $status);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td><td><?php echo $username; ?></td><td><?php echo date('M j, Y', strtotime($reg_date)); ?></td><td><?php echo $added_by; ?></td><td><?php echo $status; ?></td><td><a href="">Deactivate</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```